# How to duplicate the Liferay's Next and Previous Buttons?

Tags: jquery, liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to duplicate the next and previous buttons of the Liferay Form to show it at the top. I tried jQuery clone to achieve this. However, the button functionality doesn't seem to work.

$('.lfr-ddm-form-pagination-controls').clone(true).insertBefore(".ddm-user-view-content");

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fire/trigger a .click() on the "original" button after clicking your new button - so they are in a kind of "in sync".

```
$('#yourNewNextButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#IdOfYourForm .lfr-ddm-form-pagination-next').click();
});
```

Comment: There is no better solution ? I would expect that I should simply add a new tag and the whole pagination would be duplicated out of the box. What will happen if we need to duplicate all of the buttons? This is the best approach to solve the problem?